# react js , get siblings or parent value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react, I'm curious how to do this properly.
suppose I have this form, by clicking button, I want to get textbox value,

```
var form = React.createClass({
   submit : function(e){
      //how to get textbox value?
   },
   render : function(){
   return (
      <form>
         <input type="text" id="textbox" value="hey, get me"/>
         <button onClick={this.submit}>Get it</button>
      </form>
      );
   }
});
```

Any answer will be appreciated! thank you!

Comment: You don't want to interact with the DOM like this with React

Comment: how it should be? @MarkC.

Comment: you should use managed components in component state - read the react docs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is using refs.

> After building your component, you may find yourself wanting to "reach
>   out" and invoke methods on component instances returned from render(). [link to refs docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

Refs are basically the html elements / react instances you want to access. In this case, we want to get Input html element. We get input element by this.inputValue. Then read its value by usual js rule.

```
 var form = React.createClass({
       submit : function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log(this.inputValue.value);
       },
       render : function(){
       return (
          <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
             <input type="text" id="textbox" defaultValue="hey, get me"
               ref={ function(node){ this.inputValue = node }.bind(this) }
             />
             <button onClick={this.submit}>Get it</button>
          </form>
          );
       }
    });
```

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/57661/) for your example, you can check the console for the input value.

Another way to accomplish the same thing is to make your input a controlled element. That means you assign input's value attribute to this.state.inputValue and you pass a onChange event handler as onChange={yourInputHandlerFunction}.

See the answer which explains this way of accomplishing the same thing.

Comment: Refs can lead to unwanted DOM manipulations and should be used carefully. Also, string refs are gonna be deprecated soon (according to the docs)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of deprecation. Although in real life I have been using function callback, for simplicity I used string in the example.

Comment: The fiddle also works without `<form></form>` wrapper (I replaced them with `<div>` wrapper. I was a little confused why there were two `this.submit`. The `this.submit` inside the form can be omitted and it will still work!

Comment: @Iggy it works for when you type and enter, if there is no form tags wrapping, on enter nothing is gonna happen, however thanks to form tags and onSubmit handler it will work on enter. Actually we can put type="submit" to button and omit onClick handler of button. This would be better.

Answer (score 8):

React enforces parent-to-child unidirectional data flow.
So, there's no simple way to access data from siblings.

But, if a child changes the *state* across the component, you probably want a **state** for keeping a track of that.

Sample code:

```
var FormBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      textBox: 'hey, get me!'
    }
  },
  pressButton: function () {
    alert(this.state.textBox)
  },
  textChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({
      textBox: e.target.value
    })
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <form action='.'>
        <input type='text' placeholder={this.state.textBox} onChange={this.textChange}/>
        <button onClick={this.pressButton}> Get it </button>
      </form>
    )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<FormBox />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

JSBin demo: https://jsbin.com/koxujuwope/edit?js,output

Also, just a suggestion... You should move to ES2015

Comment: how if i want to upload image file? please help :D

Comment: @Angger ES2015 is the new version of Javascript. Has a lot of new features that help with React development. Check it out at https://babeljs.io/ . As for the file upload, check out this component: https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone

Answer (score 0):

The following code helps me to setup communication between two siblings. The setup is done in their parent during render() and componentDidMount() calls.
It is based on https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
class App extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {
    private _navigationPanel: NavigationPanel;
    private _mapPanel: MapPanel;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
    }

    // `componentDidMount()` is called by ReactJS after `render()`
    componentDidMount() {
        // Pass _mapPanel to _navigationPanel
        // It will allow _navigationPanel to call _mapPanel directly
        this._navigationPanel.setMapPanel(this._mapPanel);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div id="appDiv" style={divStyle}>
                // `ref=` helps to get reference to a child during rendering
                <NavigationPanel ref={(child) => { this._navigationPanel = child; }} />
                <MapPanel ref={(child) => { this._mapPanel = child; }} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```