# React - access siblings of an element

Tags: reactjs

I currently have li's with this in the click handler:

```
let message = event.currentTarget.innerText
event.currentTarget.className += ' pink'
```

I would like to set the className of every other li in this ul besides the one I can access by event.currentTarget.innerText. Any suggestions? Thanks

EDIT: the suggested post did not solve my problem. Can someone help me with some boilerplate on how I can set a ref on an element and access those refs in the context of a function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react js , get siblings or parent value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39693453/react-js-get-siblings-or-parent-value)

Comment: You shouldn't directly modify the attributes of refs like that; instead, I would recommend you do something like `setState({ clicked: event.currentTarget.id })` and then in your `render` method, set the className of the various `li` elements based on whether or not they are the element referenced by `this.state.clicked`

Comment: @Hamms this seems along the lines of what I'm looking for. Could you possibly code out this example? Not totally grasping how I'd differentiate seemingly identical li elements

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you have so far?

Comment: Well if you set the class based on this.state.clicked, the problem is that I need to disable it on all the other elements. If you click one, it turns pink and when you click another that turns pink, but the one you clicked previously is still pink (it should turn back to black when you click a different li)

Answer (score 0):

Solved - thanks for the help.

Have this.state.clicked be the id of the current li and have a tertiary in the li className based on if the li id is equal to this.state.clicked